# Skip GitHub dependencies with npm install

Tags: git, npm, npm-install

For a brief introduction, I have automated builds that install dependencies from NPM to run some analysis on them. So it is important to consider that, after running `npm install`, the application doesn't even need to work, I only need the dependencies.

To keep it simple, let's say my `dependencies` from package.json looks like this (there are actually more dependencies but they aren't important) :

```
"dependencies": {
  "pdf2json": "git://github.com/jmdeejay/pdf2json.git#a384122f",
  "phone": "~2.3.7",
},
```

`phone` can be installed without any problem, but `pdf2json` isn't.

When I run `npm install`, I get the following error :

```
[10:21:19][Step 1/4] npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/jmdeejay/pdf2json.git
[10:21:19][Step 1/4] npm ERR! 
[10:21:19][Step 1/4] npm ERR! fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
[10:21:19][Step 1/4] npm ERR! github.com[0: 192.30.253.112]: errno=No such file or directory
[10:21:19][Step 1/4] npm ERR! github.com[1: 192.30.253.113]: errno=No such file or directory
[10:21:19][Step 1/4] npm ERR! 
[10:21:19][Step 1/4] npm ERR! 
[10:21:19][Step 1/4] npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

I believe it might be related to the firewall of the build server or some configuration of the said server, but this is not the problem I would want to address.

I've looked at the [npm-config](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config) and [npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) documentation but I couldn't find a flag for what I want. I'd like to know : **Is there a way to skip dependencies from other sources than NPMrepository or to continue the dependencies installation when one of them fails?**

I don't need to analyze this package as it indirectly belongs to my organization, so I would be perfectly fine with skipping it, but I can't simply remove it from the `package.json` because it is used to really install the application in other scenarios.

**Edit**

There's a comment that states using `git://` might not be a good solution, but according to NPM documentation, this should work. The following screenshot comes from the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), and the fourth line matches my configuration

[image: NPM Install with Git]

I can confirm that `git://` isn't a typo, it is typed this way in the `package.json` of a project that is working. I also don't have the opportunity to change this configuration file as I do not have ownership of this project.

Comment: Did you mean `git@github.com`, not `git://github.com`? I've never used that protocol before.

Comment: @evolutionxbox well it comes from the configuration file of one of our biggest projects (and it's not a typo), so I guess it usually works in "normal" scenarios!

Comment: If I run the same command I also get the same error. `git ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/jmdeejay/pdf2json.git`. Try https instead? That works for me.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I've updated my question, I found that `git://` is supposed to work. You're right it does work with `https`, but I do not have the privilege to change this configuration file without major tweaks which I'd like to avoid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels awkward answering my own question but I found a solution with the help of @evolutionbox's comment.

I couldn't modify the `package.json` file, but I ended up doing this in my script:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf "git://"
npm install
git config --global url."git://".insteadOf "https://"
```

This way, I temporarly change my configuration to something that works (even though, according to npm's documentation, `git://` should work)